# How to simplify (loop) if else statement and get mysql table column's name (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I need help,

Scenario: Hotel, Checking Guests In. data in MySQL database.

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hotels` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Room01` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Room02` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Room03` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Room04` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Room05` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Room06` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Room07` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Room08` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Room09` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Room10` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE Name = 'hotel1'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$room01 = $row['room01'];

0 = empty, 1 = not empty.

here is my code:

```
<?php
//example
$room01=1;
$room02=1;
$room03=0;
$room04=0;
//example

if ($room01 == 0)
{
echo "Your room is room01.";
}
elseif ($room02 == 0)
{
echo "Your room is room02.";
}
elseif ($room03 == 0)
{
echo "Your room is room03.";
}
elseif ($room04 == 0)
{
echo "Your room is room04.";
}
else
{
echo "None!";
}
?>
```

Result: Your room is room03.

What if I have 100 Rooms?
How to simplify if else statement and get the room name?

Comment: Is this code you wanna use, or just an example to clarify your question ?

Comment: You need to to structure your echo statements using something like "Your room is room" + $roomNumber + ".";

Comment: Why not have the SQL check if it is/isn't empty? @RoddeyFrost the `.` is for concatenation in PHP.

Comment: Oops, been a while for PHP.  Just trying to give a generic example though.

Comment: You should probably not have one column dedicated per room. So if you have 100 rooms, you should not have 100 columns.

Comment: thanks. above code is just for clarify my question. try to not use so many if else. and of course, the code works.

Comment: check if it is/isn't empty? good question, I will think about that.

Comment: Looking at all the answers right now, I get a feeling like `Who writes the most complicated code for such a simple task?` xD

Comment: Any comment or answer here that fails to mention normalisation should be ignored. It's your only option, so read about it

Comment: @Strawberry You're right. I've updated my answer accordingly. Though I've still got a feeling that my explanation won't be enough for OP to understand it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
const EMPTY_ROOM = 0;

$roomNumber = array_search(EMPTY_ROOM, $row);
if(false === $roomNumber) {
    echo 'None!';
    return;
}

echo 'Your room is ' . $roomNumber . '.' . PHP_EOL;
```

---

**Update**

hmm, I used test data to generate input. With your table structure here's updated code:

```
function readDatabase() {
    $handle = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('stackexchange');

    if(!$handle) {
        exit(mysql_error($handle));
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE Name = 'hotel1'", $handle);

    return mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}

const EMPTY_ROOM = 0;
const OCCUPIED_ROOM = 1;

$row = readDatabase();

//use `array_slice` to get rid of columns: `id`, `Name`, `Date`. We want to search only in remaining columns: Room01, Room02 .... RoomN.
$roomNumber = array_search(EMPTY_ROOM, array_slice($row, 3));
if(false === $roomNumber) {
    echo 'None!';
    return;
}

echo 'Your room is ' . $roomNumber . '.' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I posted updated solution. Does it work for you now?

Comment: It works! all I need is to add password and modify the db name.thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (small explanation inside):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$roomNumber = 1;

//Get data from array
foreach($row as $data){
    //if room returns 0 (empty)
    if($data == 0){
        if($roomNumber < 10){
            echo "Your room is room0". $roomNumber;
            break;
        } else {
            echo "Your room is room". $roomNumber;
            break;
        }
    } else {
        $roomNumber++;
    }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that it doesn't matter how many rooms you have. You can add or remove as many as you like. It'll loop through all of them, without having to adept the code.

EDIT:

After @Strawberrys comment, I realise that although my answer will work, this is not the way you should continue. Database normalisation would be the way to go. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `hotels` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Hotel_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `Room_number` INT(5) NOT NULL,
    `Occupied` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Using this type of Database design, you can easily add and remove Hotels to your system. Using `Hotel_id` as a reference, you can now easily add and remove rooms to your Hotels, without having to use an insane amount of table columns.

To use it, you simply query the `Hotel_id` inside `rooms` to get all rooms returned. Afterwards it's just a matter of checking the first `Room_number` where `Occupied` returned 0.

Comment: You're welcome. Though I suggest not accepting an answer before you've tested it out and see if it works. I'm gratefull for the appreciation, but it would be sad if it didn't help you.

Comment: thanks, I got many rooms message, like a mess and cannot figure it out. I just added more info about the question. (mysql table)

Comment: @TankVvv Ah ofcourse you did get that. My mistake. The reason you got so many messages was because the loop didn't stop if an empty room was found. I've updated the code and it should work fine now :)

Comment: Not sure why you'd have a date in a rooms table, but definitely a step in the right direction

Comment: @Strawberry I guess OP wanted to use the date to see when the room was occupied or empty on last update. That's why I've added it.

Comment: thanks for the table advise. I will try to understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to find all empty rooms from database result and then print first room name, if any. Here's how you can write code without assuming there are `100` or `n` number of rooms in your database.

```
const EMPTY_ROOM = 0;
const OCCUPIED_ROOM = 1;

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$emptyRooms = array_filter($rows, function($room_value) {
    return EMPTY_ROOM === $room_value;
});


if(empty($emptyRooms) || !is_array($emptyRooms)) {
    echo 'None!';
    return;
}

$rooms = array_keys($emptyRooms);
echo 'Your room is ' . $rooms[0] . '.' . PHP_EOL;
```

---

Update: It's probably because strict check is failing `(EMPTY === $room_value)`. When you get data from database `$room_value` holds string data. Here's updated code:

```
function readDatabase() {
    $handle = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('stackexchange');

    if(!$handle) {
        exit(mysql_error($handle));
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE Name = 'hotel1'", $handle);

    return mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}

$row = readDatabase();

const EMPTY_ROOM = '0';//set to string value to compare against database value

//use `array_slice` to get rid of columns: `id`, `Name`, `Date`.
//We want to search only in remaining columns: Room01, Room02 .... RoomN.
$row = array_slice($row, 3);

$emptyRooms = array_filter($row, function($room_value) {
    return EMPTY_ROOM === $room_value;
});

if(empty($emptyRooms) || !is_array($emptyRooms)) {
    echo 'None!';
    return;
}

$rooms = array_keys($emptyRooms);
echo 'Your room is ' . $rooms[0] . '.' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting table structure. I posted updated solution using `array_filter` but I would recommend using `array_search` solution - posted as separate answer.